# Use AutoHotkey to implement sed like replacement on clipboard

Tags: regex, replace, sed, clipboard, autohotkey

I want to use AutoHotkey to implement sed like replacement on the clipboard. I have tried several different ways to implement it, although I would like to make something which can be easily extended and be as functional as sed. Ideally it would take the act and take the same commands as sed and replace the current clipboard with the output. Since I use Ditto I will then have both the origlinal and output saved.

The solutions I have thought of and tested are to either make a hotstring which performs one specific sed replacement, e.g. using RegExreplace:

```
; Make text in clipboard "Camel Case" (retaining all spaces):
:*:xcamelsc::
    haystack := Clipboard
    needle := "\h*([a-zA-Zåäö])([a-zåäö]*)\h*" ; this retains new lines 
    replacement := "$U1$2 "
    result := RegExReplace(haystack, needle, replacement)
    Clipboard =
    Clipboard := result
    ClipWait
    sleep 100    
    send ^v 
return
```

Another example is

```
;replace multiple underscore with one space   
:*:xr_sc::
    haystack := Clipboard
    needle := "[\h]*[\_]+"
    replacement := " "
    result := RegExReplace(haystack, needle, replacement)
    Clipboard =
    Clipboard := result
    ClipWait
return
```

The flaw with this system is that I would have to make ~500 combinations of hotstrings for each possible combination I would like to have (e.g. a separate hotstring which to make all space underscore). I am not sure how to easily extend this.

Another way to do this is to use a GUI which previews the output and makes it possible to do more things, as implemented in [clipboard replace](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/41177-clipboard-search-replace-v150/). For this to be satisfactory I have made a hotstring which opens the GUI with the initial replacement filled in, and a hotkeys which automatically performs the replacement and pastes the output, etc. This system only requires that I specify the thing to replace, but I would rather have a system similar to the above which uses variables for all possible replacements so that I can refer to e.g. /^[\t]// to directly perform replacement.

A solution to do this would be to have a hotstring activate if I type 
    "xr[a string of text to indicate what to replace][a string of text to indicate what to replace with]xx" 
i.e. "xx" would take the word just typed, parse it into the command, and perform it. 
This would mean that if I type "xr_sxx", the "*s" part would be interpreted as two separate variables, and the "*" would be assigned the needle and the "s" would be looked up in a table and then inserted in the replacement variable of the RegExReplace.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> This system only requires that I specify the thing to replace, but I
>   would rather have a system similar to the above which uses variables
>   for all possible replacements so that I can refer to e.g. /^[\t]// to
>   directly perform replacement.
>
> Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Rather than specifying [Hotstring](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) for each scenario to perform a similar function I've used a method with a [Hotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm), [Input](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm), and values stored in an [Associative Array's](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Associative_Arrays).

Here's an Example:

```
data := {"xcamelsc": ["\h*([a-zA-Zåäö])([a-zåäö]*)\h*", "$U1$2 "]
           , "xr_sc": ["[\h]*[\_]+", " "]}

f1::
    word := ""
    key := ""
    Loop {
        input, key, V L1 M T1, {Space}{Enter}{Tab}
        if (errorlevel == "EndKey:Space") {
            if (data.HasKey(word)) {
                sendInput % "{BackSpace " StrLen(word)+1 "}"
                haystack := Clipboard
                needle := data[word].1
                replacement := data[word].2
                result := RegExReplace(haystack, needle, replacement)
                Clipboard =
                Clipboard := result
                ClipWait
                sleep 100    
                send ^v 
                }
            word := ""
            Break
        }
        else {
            word .= Format("{1:L}", key)
        }
    } 
return

; Necessary for typing mistakes when using Input
$BackSpace::
    word := SubStr(word, 1, -1)
    sendInput, {BackSpace}
return 

esc::exitapp
```

Comment: Nice solution. Since it still requires that I specify each possible combination (e.g. I have to have as specific pair to have underscore replaced with tab, and another pair to have underscore replaced with space). Because of this, this will still require me to create >500 pairs, and that I add a hotkey. If it was e.g. possible to have a hotstring activate if I type 
    "x[a string of text to indicate what to replace][a string of text to indicate what to replace with]xx" 
i.e. "xx" would take the previous word and parse it into the command, and also perform the command, that would be ideal.

Comment: I provided a functional example based on the code you provided. You didn't provide enough information in your original post, in fact even your edit hasn't clarified much. You mention you have a Table to pull data from, but don't provide it. Your commands don't match. You state you want 2 values pulled from a command but your Camel example doesn't have 2 values to pull? In any case I hope you find the code I provided useful, this task is within AHK scope, the example is relevant for the fact that Hotstrings are not what you need, Input command is what will achieve the functionality you require.

Comment: Thank you @ahkcoder, it is a good solution to the stated question, but due to conflicts with other scripts I have, I can not use it and will stick to a hotstring based method which parses the hotstring and use it as input variables. The camelcase example was added rather than e.g. tab to comma to make it easer to see how it is intended to be extended, although I should probably state more examples to make it more clear.